# If Formula in SQL

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, formula

I have a piece of PHP code that creates interest on a credits system every day. The PHP code that calculates the interest looks like this (it's from an SMF forum modification):

```
// Create some money out of nowhere. How? By magical means, of course!
    $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
        UPDATE {db_prefix}members
        SET moneyBank = moneyBank + (moneyBank * {float:rate})',
        array(
            'rate' => $modSettings['shopInterest'] / 100,
        ));
```

Now, in another part of the software I make the {float:rate} equal 1% and that means every day the credits in the bank earn 1% or gain 1% interest.  From what I can tell there is no limit on this and so even if a person has a billion credits in the forum bank they'll still earn 1%.

I would like to limit the interest to the first 100,000.  And I've tried to do it this way:

```
SET moneyBank = moneyBank + (100000 * {float:rate})',
```

But of course this makes every user receive 1% of 100,000, even if they only have 100 credits. If this were an excel formula I'd make it look something like:

```
=if(moneyBank=>100000,100000*floatrate,moneyBank*floatrate)
```

i.e. if moneyBank is greater than 100000 the floatrate is only applied to the first 100000.  If moneyBank is less than 100000, apply the 1% interest to the entire moneyBank amount.

Can anyone help me make the PHP code do this?  I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
... SET moneybank = moneybank + IF(moneybank > 100000, 100000*rate, moneybank*rate)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: the portable way is to use CASE, something line CASE WHEN moneyBank<100000 then moneyBank*.01 ELSE 1000 END. Many SQL engines have IF or something like that as a function. docs for CASE (from Microsoft, but this is standard SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)